# Flask: How to terminate a python subprocess

Tags: python, html, flask, subprocess

I have 4 Scrapy spiders that I launch through Flask. How at the click of a button to shut down a particular spider? (page_id the name some spider)

start:

```html
<button id="scrape" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Scrape</button>
```

**UPDATE:** I wrote `process.pid` in mongodb and try to access it in `kill_spider`. The function is running, but the process continues.

flask:

```
@app.route('/<page_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page(page_id):
    file_py = f"{page_id}.py"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        process = subprocess.Popen('python spiders/' + file_py, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        mongo.db.processes.insert_one({'process': process.pid})
        process.wait()
```

mongodb:

[image]

stop:

```html
<a href="/kill_spider/wellness" class="btn btn-danger">Stop</a>
```

flask:

```
@app.route('/kill_spider/<page_id>')
def kill_spider(page_id):
    processes = [process for process in mongo.db.processes.find()]

    for i in processes:
        i = i['process']
        os.kill(i, signal.SIGTERM)
    mongo.db.processes.drop()
    return redirect('/' + page_id)
```

Comment: doesn't it freeze all code when you use `wait()` ? Did you see  [Popen.kill()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) in documentation ? Where do you have code for `/kill_spider` ?

Comment: if you run long-running code then maybe you should run it with threading or multiprocessing or use Celery to run it in separated program - [Using Celery With Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask)

Comment: @furas I tried using Popen.kill () and updated my question

Comment: don't you get any error message when you run it in console/terminal ? You create local variable `process` in `page()` so other functions can't access it but later you try to use `process.pid`

Comment: @furas How can I access `process.pid` from `kill_spider`?

Comment: you may have to assign to global variable using `global process` in `page()`. Eventually it may need to keep PID in some file or database if flask runs code in many threads. You can also try to keep it in `app.config["PID"] = process.pid`. If you run many spiders at the same time then you may need `list` to keep all values.

Comment: @furas I wrote `process.pid` in mongodb, but getting an error

Comment: show full error message (starting at word "Traceback"). It shows which line makes problem. You can also use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variable before saving in database and after getting from database.

Comment: @furas I added `mongo.db.processes.drop()` to remove old values. print (i) = int, e.g. 10394. The function is running, but the process continues.

Comment: you may try `signal.SIGKILL` (or value `9` which means signal `KILL`)

Comment: nothing works((